# How to identify authenticated user is admin of gsuite or not?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-workspace

I am use a PHP google sdk for my project.

I want to create a account if authenticated user is a admin of the gsuite account.

I try to find that but not able to find any single link which help me to identify account .

Can anyone help me to check that user is admin of the gsuite or not?

Here is the overview link [Click Here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) , you can check in the response ,there is one key `isAdmin` is available. But when i try out below link with `get` and `list` it return me error message something like this `"Not Authorized to access this resource/api"`

Here is the `try it out` link of the google : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the API at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/admin.googleapis.com ? I believe your project needs to be associated to a gsuite domain as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whatever account you're using doesn't have the correct permissions here.

On the `Try this API` there's a `viewType` which is set to `admin_view` by default. If you use `admin_view` you need to be an admin on the G Suite domain. This is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#retrieve_users_non_admin).

Problem is that the `isAdmin` key is only included with the `admin_view`.

All of this is actually not really important though, considering your goal. You want to be able to determine whether any user is an admin or not from within PHP code, which makes the `Try this API` part academic.

What you really need to do is to [create a serviceaccount with domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) and use this serviceaccount to authenticate the requests to the API. This serviceaccount will allow you to get the `isAdmin` key.

You can authenticate an HTTP/REST API call using the serviceaccount as indicted in [this article.](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests)